# Arduino-Makefile: do not understand how to correctly use USER_LIB_PATH

Tags: arduino

I'm using the Arduino-Makefile command-line-interface package on Linux, and recently I made an Arduino program that uses dht.h (a non-standard Arduino library) that I placed in directory /home/ramces/Sketchbook/libraries

my program includes the line:

```
#include <dht.h>
```

This is my makefile:

```
ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino
ARDUINO_PORT = /dev/ttyACM*
USER_LIB_PATH = /home/ramces/Sketchbook/libraries/DHT/ dht.h
BOARD_TAG = uno
ARDUINO_LIBS = LiquidCrystal
include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

non-standard libraries are imported with the USER_LIB_PATH variable, however, the issue is that I don't know how to properly use USER_LIB_PATH. I looked at the documentation on git-hub but I am still not sure how USER_LIB_PATH is used correctly.

When I try loading the program to the Arduino microcontroller, with the command:

```
sudo make upload clean
```

the compilation stops with the error message:

```
/home/ramces/Sketchbook/libraries/DHT//dht.cpp:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

However, if I just leave the USER_LIB_PATH variable as:

```
USER_LIB_PATH = /home/ramces/Sketchbook/libraries/DHT
```

I get another error:

```
    therm1.ino:2:17: fatal error: dht.h: No such file or directory
 #include <dht.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk:1215: recipe for target 'build-uno/therm1.o' failed
make: *** [build-uno/therm1.o] Error 1
```

The documentation on using USER_LIB_PATH (https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/master/Arduino.mk) from git-hub has this:

```
# If you have your additional libraries relative to your source, rather
# than in your "sketchbook", also set USER_LIB_PATH, like this example:
#
#       USER_LIB_PATH := $(realpath ../../libraries)
```

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc, but that didn't work, I edited the question to account for the error that this gives me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to move your DHT library. Use `USER_LIB_PATH` to specify the "root directory" where additional libraries are stored.

The libraries used are listed in `ARDUINO_LIBS`.

So the following should accomplish this:

```
USER_LIB_PATH = /home/ramces/Sketchbook/libraries/
ARDUINO_LIBS = LiquidCrystal dht
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux you need to be careful of the case of your folder/filenames... Linux (unlike windows) is case sensitive. ie
**Sketchbook** is **NOT the same** as **sketchbook**.

So is your Sketchbook folder

```
/home/ramces/Sketchbook/libraries/DHT
```

OR all lower case like

```
/home/ramces/sketchbook/libraries/DHT
```

The same applies to your DHT folder. What is the case of that folder?

So Check the CASE of your Files/foldernames.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am well aware of the case specificity of Linux and I made sure that it is correctly addressed. My directory is capital S in Sketchbook directory. Also, DHT is call capital letters. The directories are all correct case, I double checked.

Answer (score 0):

One way I got around this issue is by moving my non-standard library dht.h along with another file that came with it dht.cpp into a new directory called dht which had to manually be placed inside the standard Arduino library directory as a root user otherwise permission to modify the standard Arduino library directory (located in: /usr/share/arduino/libraries) is denied. Also, I had to change the ARDUINO_LIBS variable to:

```
ARDUINO_LIBS = LiquidCrystal dht
```

since by default, ARDUINO_LIBS will check the standard Arduino libraries directory for any library specified in the variable ARDUINO_LIBS.

This does not solve the issue with USER_LIB_PATH, but it lets the user circumvent the issue of not being able to use a non-standard Arduino library for using certain sensors such as the humidity and temperature sensor library dht.h.The program was able to be compiled without issues and the sensor and LCD are now able to perform the program that was uploaded to the Arduino micro-controller.